# Is it safe to hold references to attributes of the same struct by using 'static?

Tags: rust, unsafe

On tricky problem impossible to do without unsafe blocks, is holding in a struct references to something owned by an other attribute of this struct.

However, with unsafe blocks it's quite easy, one can do something like:

```rust
struct Foo {
    bar: &'static str,
    foo: String
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(s: String) -> Foo {
        Foo {
            bar: unsafe { ::std::mem::transmute(&s[..]) },
            foo: s
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the question: provided no method of the struct `Foo` previously defined gives `&mut` access to it (the struct will thus never be modified after creation), knowing that the data of `String` is heap-allocated, is this code actually safe (according to rust meaning of "safe")? If not, what are the situations where a problem may arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&mut` access is not (that) important. What's important is that the `String` is never changed (at least without the `&'static str` also being changed), other data can change for all we care. Besides, if a `&mut` would allow third party code to change the string, then they could also change it without a pointer, via inherited mutability:

```
let x = Foo::new(string);
let mut x = x;
x.foo = other_string;
println!("{}", x.bar); //
```

So at the very least you must keep the attribute private and audit all code in the same module (not just the `impl Foo`!). There's another problem though:
If you *ever* hand out the `&'static str`, then yes, it is unsafe:

```
let x = Foo::new(string);
let s: &'static str = obtain_str(x);
drop(x);
println!("{}", s); // use after free
```

So what you can do safely with this kind of self-reference is *very* limited. The second problem could, *maybe*, be prevented with appropriate use of lifetimes, but this gets into the area where I'm not willing to accept safety without an elaborate semi-formal argument.

For the use cases I imagine, it is probably easier to bite the bullet and stay away from `unsafe`.

Comment: I see. So, assuming all fields are private, and the only access to the contents is made through a method like `pub fn get_str<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str { &self.bar }`, what could possibly go wrong ?

Comment: @Levans Lots of things, I'd wager. Or maybe nothing at all. As I said, I'm out of my depth here: I can point out safety holes as I find them, but not finding any doesn't give me much confidence.